My liar co-worker negatively projecting my image
I am in IT. I use virtual machine. When mute the laptop, on virtual machine it does not get muted. First time I had checked with my co-worker, asked her if she can hear, she said no it is muted. Another day, there was an online coaching with the boss. In my consciousness the sound was muted. In the middle of the coaching class, she started telling the boss that it is so noisy and that there are dogs barking at my place. I was surprised, like a blow on my face. The boss acting professionally said if the dogs bark then the person is not to be blamed. It's not the person's fault. I added an explanation, that at this time people are commuting from work to house and as dogs see passing by the bark. He kinda understood. I kept imagining what would it be if the boss was not reasonable, what if he had said not a suitable place to work or negative things. This clearly shows my coworker been lying, manipulating things in her own terms.
How can I deal with such co-worker?
At times I feel I don't wanna work with her. Even wanna punish her for the bad she tried do to me

Are you absolutely sure she is intentionally lying? Saying that she can’t hear sound from you (your microphone?) and understanding whether your two-layer setup is technically muted are two different things that one would likely conflate if not aware of your setup.

Hanlon's Razor

Rather than go into a spiral of despair about a minor act of carelessness, how about focus your energy on your job.

Thank you @GregoryCurrie . It is true but she is responsible to give feedback over my work. If a person seems liar, and she is responsible to give feedback about my work, it brings me bad feelings. It is more about her character. It's not about what she did.

My proposal is to just take a deep breath, relax for a few seconds, and then think about the problem with a different mindset.
Your first mistake (the way I see it) is that you use hard words to express yourself (see "liar", "manipulative", "like a blow on my face"...). Even if that is true (which you can hardly prove), the language is not well chosen.
Second: Drivers on computers, as well as programs, are known to be badly written. Conferencing software, probably even worse. In our office, it is known that people sometimes need to restart their computers during conferences - because of microphone or speaker problems. In your setup, the situation in even worse, considering that you use virtual machines.
So, all in all, you should find a way to verify what works and what doesn't, without the help of your colleagues. Or at least, every time when you suspect that something is wrong, ask your colleagues for feedback.
Another hint: I notice that conferencing software (I already used 2 or 3 of them) have the habit of showing somehow from which users is the sound coming. So if you see that you are "tagged" as creating sound (barking or whatever), then mute your mic. As a matter of fact, you should always keep your mike muted when you do not need to say something.
Another thing: if you use the conferencing from the virtual machine (that is the feeling that I get from your post), then it is obviously useless to cancel the mike on the real machine. The virtual machine will still capture the microphone.

In my consciousness the sound was muted

The other people hear the sound from the computer, not the voice of your consciousness. You need to make sure that you mute the mike of the computer, not your inner thoughts.

she started telling the boss that it is so noisy and that there are dogs barking at my place

She most likely used the feature I mentioned before: the conferencing software was tagging you as a source of sound / noise. If two users were tagged, and one was talking and one "barking", then the math was simple.

When mute the laptop, on virtual machine it does not get muted.

Exactly as expected. That is the normal behavior. If it would be different, it would be a bug.

Even wana punish her for the bad she tried do to me

This is definitely a bad attitude from your side. Your behavior should be toward solving problems, not about being the one punishing others.

I feel I don't wana work with her.

Probably she feels that she does not want to work with you. It is called life. As employees at the same company (colleagues) you both must make efforts to have a professional behavior and good professional relationship.

Thank you for breaking into sections and answering every section.  No there is no tagging, we were in work from home method, calling through Microsoft Teams on Virtual Machine. At that moment, I was a newbie and she had joined earlier than me. That's only one of the example of things she did to me. There are many more things.  I wanted to keep the story short here.

@Pax Teams shows some indication of which user is currently producing sound. I don't remember exactly what it is, maybe a glowing circle around the user or a mic symbol, but it's able to determine that (usually) and show it visually.
